# Does the origin of Sentinel-2 L1C images on AWS represent a point at the center of the pixel or a point at the upper left corner?

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

Does the origin of [Sentinel-2 L1C images on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/sentinel-2/) represent a point at the center of the pixel or the upper left corner of the pixel? i.e. AREA_OR_POINT=Point, whether AREA_OR_POINT=Area means that a pixel value should be assumed to represent a sampling over the region of the pixel and AREA_OR_POINT=Point means a point sample at the center of the pixel.
Here's an example of 'asoc' box from a Sentinel-2 image

```
<XMLContent>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengeospatial.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlJP2Profile/1.0.0/gmlJP2Profile.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
      <gml:Null>withheld</gml:Null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <gml:FeatureCollection>
        <gml:featureMember>
          <gml:RectifiedGridCoverage dimension="2" gml:id="RGC0001">
            <gml:rectifiedGridDomain>
              <gml:RectifiedGrid dimension="2">
                <gml:limits>
                  <gml:GridEnvelope>
                    <gml:low>1 1</gml:low>
                    <gml:high>10980 10980</gml:high>
                  </gml:GridEnvelope>
                </gml:limits>
                <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
                <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
                <gml:origin>
                  <gml:Point gml:id="P0001" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32723">
                    <gml:pos>399965 8700035</gml:pos>
                  </gml:Point>
                </gml:origin>
                <gml:offsetVector srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32723">10 0</gml:offsetVector>
                <gml:offsetVector srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32723">0 -10</gml:offsetVector>
              </gml:RectifiedGrid>
            </gml:rectifiedGridDomain>
            <gml:rangeSet>
              <gml:File>
                <gml:fileName>gmljp2://codestream/0</gml:fileName>
                <gml:fileStructure>Record Interleaved</gml:fileStructure>
              </gml:File>
            </gml:rangeSet>
          </gml:RectifiedGridCoverage>
        </gml:featureMember>
      </gml:FeatureCollection>
    </gml:featureMember>
  </gml:FeatureCollection>
</XMLContent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates in the `<gml:origin>` in your example encode the **center point** of the upper left pixel.

This is consistent with the fact that `<gml:low>` in `<gml:GridEnvelope>` is `1`, and with the fact that Sentinel-2 tiling grid is aligned so that the corner of the first pixel of your tile is at `(399960, 8700040)` (this is what `tileInfo.json` should report).